# Iterate by row without FOR - not generic function for "apply"

Tags: r

```
# Custom DF
demo <- data.frame(step = seq(1:5), x1 = sample(1:5, 5), x2 = sample(5:9, 5))

# Add column with a result of some operation on subset before this row
demo <- transform(demo, res = 0)

# Fill in "res" with result of operation on several rows (subset) and some coefficients
for (k in 2:nrow(demo)) demo$res[k] <- demo$x1[k] * 2.0 + demo$x1[k - 1] * 3.0
```

**Question** : Is it possible to replace loop with "apply" or any other iterator with these conditions

- callback function (FUN) for "apply" should know index of current row
- also, I need to have access to initial DF from FUN

I can simulate index this way :

```
cycle <- function(k) { k }
lapply(1:nrow(demo), cycle) # use sequence instead of DF itself
```

This code will print indices from 1 to 5 but how to pass demo as argument into "cycle"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no one-size-fits-all solution to this type of problem. In this particular case you don't need for loops or apply. You can just use vectored operations

```
demo$res <- c(0,tail(demo$x1,-1)*2 + head(demo$x1,-1)*3)
```

The `dplyr` library has nice `lead/lag` functions which can make these operations easier.

```
library(dplyr)
demo %>% mutate(res2=x1*2 + lag(x1)*3)
# this values the first value as NA rather than 0
```

It is also possible to pass additional arguments to function in `lapply`. For example you can do

```
cycle <- function(k, d) { paste(k, d[[1]][k]) }
lapply(1:nrow(demo), cycle, demo)
```

The parameters that are being iterated over are passed as the first parameter, and then you can just include additional parameters in the `lapply` call itself and they are passed along to the child function.